# {React Native} Resetting Formik form after submit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am stuck at resetting my form after it has been submitted.

Here is what I have

```
  const PostEvent = () =>{

        //Omitted code for brevity. 

return(
    <Formik
         initialValues ={{user: userName.currentUser.displayName, description: '',datePosted: new Date(), location: '', eventDate: '', title: ''}}
         onSubmit ={(values, {resetForm}) =>{
                 firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').add({
                     datePosted: values.datePosted.toDateString(),
                     description: values.description, 
                     eventDate: date.toDateString(),
                     eventTime: date.toTimeString(),
                     location: values.location,
                     title: values.title,
                     user: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
                     userId : firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
                     });
                 resetForm({values:''})
                 }}> 
         {props =>(

         <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
         <DismissKeyBoard>
         <View style={{flex:1}}>
             <View  style={styles.form}><Text  style={styles.text}>Pick a place for the event</Text></View>
             <View style= {{paddingTop:20}}>
                 <GoogleAutocomplete 
                     placeholder = 'Insert place to post about '
                     onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                             {props.values.location = data.description}
                         }}>     
                 </GoogleAutocomplete>
             </View >

                <View style={styles.form}>    

                 <Text style={styles.text}>{userName.currentUser.displayName}</Text>
                 <TextInput
                     placeholder= 'Title of the event'
                     onChangeText = {props.handleChange('title')} 
                     style={styles.text}/>
                 <TextInput
                     placeholder= 'Description (e.g This is located...)'
                     multiline={true}
                     onChangeText = {props.handleChange('description')}
                     values = {props.values.description} 
                     style={styles.textBox}/>

                 <Text  style={styles.text} >Click on the below icons to pick a time and a date for the event</Text>

                 <DateTimeImage onPress={showTimepicker} name = 'alarm'>Time?</DateTimeImage> 
                 <DateTimeImage onPress={showDatepicker} name = 'calendar'>Date?</DateTimeImage> 

                  {show && (<DateTimePicker onChange={onChange} value = {date} mode = {mode}></DateTimePicker>)}

                 <Button onPress={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>

                 </View>    

         </View>       
         </DismissKeyBoard>     
         </ScrollView>
         )}
     </Formik> 
 )
}
```

This task should be pretty trivial, but I cannot seem to have it work. I have looked at many tutorials and SO posts, and they all seem to have the same idea, which is to pass a callback reset function to the `onSubmit` prop of the `<Formik>` component. 
Anyone has any idea of what I could try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reset the form the values should be of the format of initialValues. You can take out the initalValues as an object and pass it on to reset form

```
const initialValues = {
      user: userName.currentUser.displayName, 
      description: '',
      datePosted: new Date(), 
      location: '', 
      eventDate: '', 
      title: ''
}

..
<Formik
     initialValues ={initialValues}
     onSubmit ={(values, {resetForm}) =>{
             firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').add({
                 datePosted: values.datePosted.toDateString(),
                 description: values.description, 
                 eventDate: date.toDateString(),
                 eventTime: date.toTimeString(),
                 location: values.location,
                 title: values.title,
                 user: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
                 userId : firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
                 });
             resetForm({values: initialValues})
             }}>
```

Linked [github issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/446)

Comment: Thank you taking the time to help. I did as you suggested above, but unfortunately I still do not get my values to reset within the form. I wonder if the `<GoogleAutocomplete>` component is messing with it?

Comment: Does the description field also not reset

Comment: Yes nothing reset. I purposely tried to  'values = {props.values.description} ' in the description to check the rendering of the value, but it does not reset at all.

Comment: I did a sample demo here with react and it works https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-sw5x2?file=/index.js

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a reproducible demo with react-native and share

Comment: I can try to do that. Interestingly enough, after looking at your demo I changed my `value= {props.values.title}` value for the title and it does empty out once the form is submitted. All the rest stays the exact same though.

Comment: Your description field has incorrect prop. Should have been `value= {props.values.description} `. That is why it isn't cleared. The other fields need value prop too in order for reset to be effective